# batch transactions and execute it gaslessly using safe-core-sdk relay kit

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core-sdk

I want to batch erc20 transfers and execute them gaslessly using a safe core AA relay kit. For example https://github.com/safe-global/safe-apps-sdk/tree/main/guides/drain-safe-app this transaction but gaslessly